# c# listview string extraction for mapping printers

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview with a list of network printer share names i.e. \\server\printer1.pcl5
If I try to convert the listview.selecteditems.tostring() it adds other data around the string so does not work, also the printer shares in c# need additional \\ to resolve the name.

2 questions really, how do I convert \\server\\printer1.pcl5 to \\\\server\\printer1.pcl5 when double clicking on the listview item

then how to I insert that into the addwindowsprinterconnection bit where SHAREDPRINTERNAMEGOESHERE? as it does not convert to a string properly from a listviewitem it stores it as "ListViewItem {\\server\printer1.pcl5}"

```
private void ListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {

            WshNetwork objNetwork = new WshNetwork();
            objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection("SHAREDPRINTERNAMEGOESHERE", "HPLJ4100", "\\\\SERVER\\main printer");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to get value of the selected item? This WILL NOT work:

```
listView1.SelectedItems.ToString()
```

What the above code is doing is getting the fully qualified name of the type of the Object, which in this case is a collection of ListViewItems.

To get the actual value of the selected item you'll have to go:

```
string printerShareName = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Keeping in mind that if you have MultiSelect switched on, the above code will only get the 1st item of the selection.

EDIT:

Then if you want to add your printer with the additional backslashes prefixed:

```
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection("SHAREDPRINTERNAMEGOESHERE", "HPLJ4100", "\\" + printerShareName);
```

Comment: That great thanks (multiselect off), it seems to map the printer even though im only entering it with the single backslashes too which is good